# C# less than by a certain amount

Tags: c#

I have a simple loop here:

```
for (; ; )
        {
            if (start == end)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                {
                    if (start > end)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{F9}");
                        File.WriteAllText(path, String.Empty);
                        createText = "bind F9 \"exec odymod\"" + Environment.NewLine;
                        createText = cmd + " " + start + Environment.NewLine;
                        File.WriteAllText(path, createText);
                        start = start - inc;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{F9}");
                        File.WriteAllText(path, String.Empty);
                        createText = "bind F9 \"exec odymod\"" + Environment.NewLine;
                        createText = cmd + " " + start + Environment.NewLine;
                        File.WriteAllText(path, createText);
                        start = start + inc;
                    }
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
                }
            }
        }
```

However, I run into a problem. I am trying to break the loop once start = the end, which works, however, if inc is a decimal then start will never truly equal end. Is there a way that I can see if instead of being exactly equal to another number, that I can see if its within a set range of that number? For example, I wanna see if start is within 0.5 of end, then break.

Comment: `if (Math.Abs(start - end) < tolerance) break;` where `tolerance == 0.5`

Comment: Non-related to your question, but you could write your loop as `while (start != end) { ... }`

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but you're setting the value of `createText` to something and then immediately (next line) overwriting it with a different value. You can also simplify a bit by pulling everything out of the inner if/else *except* for the `start=` line : `SendKeys.SendWait("{F9}"); ... File.WriteAllText(path, createText); if(start>end) { start=start-inc; } else { start = start + inc; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if `start` within *some range* of `end` you can use `Math.Abs`:

```
 const double tolerance = 0.5;

 ...

 if (Math.Abs(start - end) < tolerance)
   break;
```

which means "if `start` is close enough to `end` (absolute value of the difference is less than `tolerance` then `break` the loop)".

You can simplify the initial `for(;;)` loop into

```
// keep looping while start is not close enough to end 
while (Math.Abs(start - end) >= tolerance) {
  if (start > end) {
    ...
  }
  else {
    ...
  } 
}
```

Comment: @J.Doe don't forget to mark this answer as correct.

Comment: By the way, decimals,unlike floats can be exactly equal. You don't show your type declarations, but you mention decimal (you should show your type declarations BTW). For what it's worth, you should probably stick with doubles (or even floats, perhaps) and use the "tolerance" example above. This is the classic reference everyone will eventually point you to (though I wish there was a simpler to read version): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html